# How should i use final variable to create limit in decrementing carousel?

Tags: java

Decrementing Carousel is a container, accepting int elements. DecrementingCarousel has a maximum capacity, specified via the constructor. When created, DecrementingCarousel is in accumulating state: you may add elements via the addElement method and can produce a CarouselRun object via the run method. Once the run method is called, DecrementingCarousel is in running state: it refuses adding more elements.

The CarouselRun allows to iterate over elements of the carousel decrementing them one by one with the next method. The next returns the value of the current element.Then it decreases the current element by one and switches to the next element.

The CarouselRun iterates over elements in the order of their insertion.
When an element is decreased to zero, the CarouselRun will skip it in further iterations. When there are no more elements available for decrementing, the CarouselRun returns -1.

The CarouselRun also has the isFinished method, which indicates, if the carousel has run out of the lements to decrement.

DecrementingCarouselWithLimitedRun - Decrementing Carousel's subclass. DecrementingCarouselWithLimitedRun must decrement elements as a usual DecrementingCarousel. The difference is that this implementation must produce a carousel run, which limits number of calls to the next method. When the limit of calls reached carousel run must consider itself finished.

CarouselRun:

```
public class CarouselRun {
    protected final int[] array = DecrementingCarousel.carousel.clone();
    protected int position = 0;

    public int next() {
        if (isFinished())
            return -1;
        else {
            while (array[position %= array.length] <= 0) {
                position++;
            }
        }
        var returnValue = array[position];
        array[position] = array[position] -1 ;
        position = position + 1;
        return returnValue;
    }
    public boolean isFinished() {
        for (int el : array)
            if (el > 0)
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

DecrementingCarousel:

```
public class DecrementingCarousel {
    private final int capacity;
    static int[] carousel;
    int index;
    boolean isRun;

    {
        index = 0;
        isRun = false;
    }

    public DecrementingCarousel(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        carousel = new int[capacity];
    }

    public boolean addElement(int element){
        if (element > 0 && index < capacity && !isRun) {
            carousel[index++] = element;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public CarouselRun run() {
        if (!isRun) {
            isRun = true;
            return new CarouselRun();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

DecrementingCarouselWithLimitedRun:

```
public class DecrementingCarouselWithLimitedRun extends DecrementingCarousel {
    public DecrementingCarouselWithLimitedRun(final int capacity, final int actionLimit) {
        super(capacity);
    }
    @Override
    public CarouselRun run() {
        if (!isRun) {
            isRun = true;
            return new CarouselBase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

CarouselBase:

```
public class CarouselBase extends CarouselRun {
    public int decrement = 1;
    @Override
    public int next() {
        int beforeDecreasing;
        if (isFinished())
            return -1;
        else {
            beforeDecreasing = array[position];
            array[position] -= decrement;
            do {
                position++;
            }
            while (array[position %= array.length] <= 0 && !isFinished());
        }
        return beforeDecreasing;
    }
}
```

I need to create cycle limit using "actionLimit" variable.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing so? What is the specific problem you’re having?

Comment: I just dont know how to use varible "actionLimit" to limit the number of actions.

Comment: Tbh I can't make heads or tails of these classes; there's no direct connection between `CarouselRun.next` and the `DecrementingCarousel` hierarchy other than setting `isRun`. If these are the classes you have to work with then `DecrementingCarousel.run` is the place where you'd check `actionLimit` and determine whether or not to return a new `CarouselBase`.

Comment: That said I'd probably toss all this and start over.

Comment: In this task i have complited `CorouselRun` and `DecrementingCarousel` and i need too implement `DecrementingCarouselWithLimitedRun`. This subclass must decrement elements as a usual `DecrementingCarousel`. The difference is that this implementation must produce a carousel run, which limits number of calls to the next method. So I thought that I should get value of the `actionLimit` and somehow use this value in `CarouselBase`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: `CarouselBase` has no notion of limiting runs. The `DecrementingCarousel` hierarchy appears to have an `isRun` property: the default impl returns a new `CarouselBase` if it's false; my first guess is you'd want logic in `DecrementingCarouselWithLimitedRun.run` that checks if the `actionLimit` has been reached and **doesn't** return a new `CarouselBase` under that condition.

Answer (score 0):

first you had to define a field in the constructor:

```
  public class DecrementingCarouselWithLimitedRun extends DecrementingCarousel {
public final int actionLimit;
public DecrementingCarouselWithLimitedRun(final int capacity, final int actionLimit) {
    super(capacity);
    this.actionLimit=actionLimit;

}

public CarouselRun run() {
    if (!call) {
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, i);
        call = true;
        return new CarouselBase(this.actionLimit);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

```
 class CarouselBase extends CarouselRun {
public int ss;
public  CarouselBase ( final int actionLimit) {
    this.ss = actionLimit;
}
public int next() {
    if (isFinished()) {
        return -1;
    } else while (ar[k = k % ar.length] <= 0) {
        ++k;
    }
    ss--;
    return ar[k++]--;
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
public boolean isFinished() {
    if (ss == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for (int value : ar)
            if (value > 0) {
                return false;
            }

        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).